# When to use windbg to debug?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I understand how powerful windbg can be at debugging, but when is an appropriate or best time to use it to debug an issue? Is it more issue specific, or just experience, intuition, and knowing that using it can just get the job done best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little bit of all those things, and a lot of personal perference. Many WinDbg people only use WinDbg so that's what they are best at debugging with.

WinDbg also has some good extensions out there like SOS. So a particular extension might provide you with the specific piece of information that another debugger does not.

One reason to use a different debugger in certain circumstances is if you believe the debugger is incorrect. This is rare of course. For things like stack walking for instance, the debuggers use different methods, so you can confirm the stack is what you expect by using the other.

So sum up, for most issues it doesn't matter. It's whatever you are best at using. For some particular issues it's what you say, knowing which tool is the best for that particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

While Windbg is also a fine tool for user-mode debugging, if you end up doing kernel-mode debugging it is really the only serious choice.

The kernel-mode debugging scenario often involves two machines, a debugger and a debuggee. You will be running Windbg on a debugger machine which is connected to the debuggee over a serial connection, Firewire or USB. In this scenario you can "freeze" the target machine and have full control over everything running on it. Often your debuggee (the target) will be a virtual machine running under VMWare or similar -- in this case the connection also typically uses virtual serial ports.

Here are instructions from VMWare on how to set up kernel debugging of a virtual machine:

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_devices_serial_advanced_example_debugging.html

You can also use VirtualKD which makes the setup easier and the connection much faster:

http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org/

You can also use Windbg for local kernel debugging. In this case, you only have a single machine where you connect Windbg to the running kernel. You cannot "freeze" the machine, as it would also freeze Windbg running on the same machine, but you can analyze the contents of memory and so on.

Comment: Is kernel-mode debugging for total system crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Good point. Another good solution for virtual kernel debugging is LiveKd from sysinternals.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897415.aspx